# javascript objects as parameters not returning correct object

Tags: javascript

I am working on a codecademy javascript course, and in this one i have to return the older age of two people. For some reason it is returning the younger age, cant figure it out for the life of me.

```
// Our person constructor
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
// We can make a function which takes persons as arguments
// This one computes the difference in ages between two people
var ageDifference = function(person1, person2){
    return person1.age - person2.age;
}
// Make a new function, olderAge, to return the age of
// the older of two people
function olderAge(){
    if(alice > billy){
        return alice.age;
    }
    else{
        return billy.age;
    }
}


// Let's bring back alice and billy to test our new function
var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

console.log("The older person is " + olderAge(alice, billy));
```

Comment: How exactly you can define if an object is greater than another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function that compares ages is comparing the objects not the `age` parameter of the object. So this function:

```
function olderAge() {
  if (alice > billy) {
    return alice.age;
  } else {
    return billy.age;
  }
}
```

Should be:

```
function olderAge(a, b) {
  if (a.age > a.age) {
    return a.age;
  } else {
    return b.age;
  }
}
```

**Putting it all together**

I suggest changing your code to this -- we fix the `olderAge`:

```
// Our person constructor
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// We can make a function which takes persons as arguments
// This one computes the difference in ages between two people
var ageDifference = function(person1, person2){
    return person1.age - person2.age;
}

// Make a new function, olderAge, to return the age of
// the older of two people
function olderAge(a, b) {
    if (a.age > b.age){
        return a.age;
    } else {
        return b.age;
  }
}


// Let's bring back alice and billy to test our new function
var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

console.log("The older person is " + olderAge(alice, billy));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ae24v92/2/

Comment: thank you, this is returning the correct age now. However, i am now getting this error..         Oops, try again. It looks like your olderAge function fails when the first Person is older! It should return the age of the older person

Comment: @CASEYBAILEY: I guess the issue is that you are using global variables in `olderAge`, not the arguments passed to it.

Comment: @FelixKling I glazed over that -- I updated with the fix.

Comment: thank you for your effor i am now getting "The older person is [object Object]" returned i think it is something to do with codecademy. some of there lessons are stupid specific

Comment: @CASEYBAILEY On the JSFiddle, I added a toString method to the Person class. If you add that, the Person object will be converted to a string nicely.

Comment: "Oops, try again. Your olderAge function seems to be returning something other than a number. The function should return the AGE of the older person" now i am getting this with the tostring. this thing is driving me nuts hah... thanks for your help man ..

Comment: @CASEYBAILEY Oh, in that case, you need to really return the number not the object. I didn't realize. I'll update again.

Comment: @CASEYBAILEY Updated to return the numeric age.

Comment: @Cymen thank you so much.... could you tell me how the other was not returning properly but still returning the older age?

Comment: @CASEYBAILEY because it was accessing `alice` and `bill` as from the outer scope. If you changed it so alice was younger than bill, it would be wrong because it was hard coded to return alice as always being older. It was also compared the objects with `alice > bill` but that equality check was not on the age!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    // Our person constructor
    function Person (name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    // We can make a function which takes persons as arguments
    // This one computes the difference in ages between two people
    var ageDifference = function(person1, person2){
        return person1.age - person2.age;
    };
    // Make a new function, olderAge, to return the age of
    // the older of two people
    function olderAge(){
        if(alice.age > billy.age){
            return alice.age;
        }else{
            return billy.age;
        }
    }
    // Let's bring back alice and billy to test our new function
    var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
    var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);
    console.log("The older person is " + olderAge(alice, billy));
</script>
```

You missed the ".age" in comparison..